# Acionar duas funções com eventos onscroll distintos - JS

Tags: javascript, rolamento, eventos, javascript-eventos

Bom dia,

Necessito de um auxilio, tenho duas funções que utilizam o evento onscroll, uma função para aparecer um botão de "Voltar ao Topo" onde ao ele ser apresentado ao usuário ele pode ser acionado e será retornado ao topo da página e uma outra de esconder parte do navbar da página ao descer um pouco a página, porém, ao incluir ambos, somente um deles funciona. A minha dúvida é a seguinte, eu só posso incluir um evento onscroll no arquivo? Teria algum modo de eu aplicar ambas as funções no mesmo arquivo?

Abaixo seguem ambos os códigos em js que estou utilizando:

Esconder o NavBar:

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;

window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
      if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
          document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
         } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
}
prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
};
```

Botão Voltar ao Topo:

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 
20) {
        document.getElementById("Topo").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("Topo").style.display = "none";
    }
}

function VoltarTopo() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0; 
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; 
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você usar o método `addEventListener`, você pode adicionar mais de um método para ser executado a cada evento.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', method1);
window.addEventListener('scroll', method2);
```

Para cancelar/parar de receber o evento `scroll`:

```
window.removeEventListener('scroll', method1);
```

Mas também não tem porque adicionar 2 *listeners* de scroll p/ disparar dois métodos diferentes que estão na mesma página. Seguindo o que você fez até então, vc pode isolar o bloco que implementa seu `window.onscroll` em um novo método, seria algo assim:

```
function method1(event) { ... }
function method2(event) { ... }

window.onscroll = function (event) {
  method1(event);
  method2(event);
}
```

Comment: Cara funcionou perfeitamente, Muito obrigado mesmo, estou aprendendo Javascript ainda e ja estou com umas buchas pra resolver hehe, muito obrigado mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode incluir várias functions ou códigos respondendo um evento, basta fazer assim:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction();
  outraFunction();
}
```

Você pode ainda usar o "bom e velho" `addEventListener`, assim:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollFunction);
window.addEventListener('scroll', outraFunction);
```

Comment: Cara funcionou perfeitamente, Muito obrigado mesmo, estou aprendendo Javascript ainda e ja estou com umas buchas pra resolver hehe, muito obrigado mesmo!